# How can I calculate the biggest distance between points inside a OpenCV's countour?

Tags: python, opencv

Actually, in this picture, there is only one contour, but I'd need the biggest distance between points in both regions

In [image: Box with 1 contour]

```
im1 = cv.imread('g1.jpg')
img_white = np.zeros([512,512,1],dtype=np.uint8)
img_white.fill(255)

src_gray = cv.cvtColor(im1, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
src_gray = cv.blur(src_gray, (3,3))
threshold = 100
canny_output = cv.Canny(src_gray, threshold, threshold * 2)
contours, _ = cv.findContours(canny_output, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
_ = cv.drawContours(img_white, contours,10,(0,255,0), 3)
```

Comment: could you provide the original image?

Comment: Each contour is a set of points. So the only way is to check each contours and every point pair in this contour.  So the complexity would be O(C*fact(S)), where C is amount of contours, S is average number of points in contour. Let me know if you're interested in full code example for such answer.